# Function that removes numbers less than 10 in a list

Tags: racket

I need to create a function which takes a list of numbers and removes all numbers less than 10 and outputs a new list.

So far I have this:

```
#lang racket


(define less-than10(lambda (x)
  (for/list ([i x] #:when (lambda (x) (< x 10))) i)))


(less-than10 '(1 2 3 4 11))
```

however, it still does not remove numbers less than 10. It just outputs the exact same list. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the predicate to the bound loop variable *`i`*, also note that I have flipped the predicate:

```
#lang racket

(define less-than10
  (lambda (x)
    (for/list ([i x] #:when ((lambda (x) (> x 10)) i)) i)))

(less-than10 '(1 2 3 4 11))
; => '(11)
```

A more natural version would use `filter`:

```
(define less-than10.v2
  (lambda (x)
    (filter (lambda (x) (> x 10)) x)))

(less-than10.v2 '(1 2 3 4 11))
; => '(11)
```